# What is Searchable configuration, searchable activity?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-search

I am designing a simple search feature for my application, I have Successfully created a search icon on the toolbar of my screen. Now I'm having problems in implementing brains (working) behind the search feature

- Through Android's official documentation for setting up search interface, I
  came across this various procedure of creating a **searchable configuration**, 
  **searchable activity**, **ACTION_SEARCH**!
- I'm new to android development, I'm having a tough time in understanding all these concepts, Can someone explain the above procedure in simple terms?

Comment: I would suggest looking up blogs on searchview . It will help you to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Through Android's official documentation for setting up search
>      interface, I came across this various procedure of creating a
>      searchable configuration, searchable activity, ACTION_SEARCH!
> 2. I'm new to android development, I'm having a tough time in
>      understanding all these concepts, Can someone explain the above
>      procedure in simple terms?

Well, It's easy. First, Read the [**Creating a Search Interface**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html). Second, Starts from [**here**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableConfiguration) by adding an xml in the `res/xml/` project directory.

Then, You'll need to create a **Searchable *Activity*** by following link:

**[Creating a Searchable Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity)**

After creating the `Searchable Activity`, You'll need to declare it on `AndroidManifest.xml`, Just add the following to your `SearchableActivity`:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

After all these, Read this : [**PerformingSearch**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#PerformingSearch) And Receive the query from your Activity when user do the searches(Like `MainActivity` to `SearchableActivity`).

Answer (score 0):

Inflate the XML menu resource (res/menu/options_menu.xml) in the onCreateOptionsMenu() method of your activity:and getMenu Item .Write following code

```
MenuItem searchItem=menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenu);
SearchView searchView=(SearchView)                
MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+query,     
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I put the above code into the onCreate..(), I get this error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.View android.view.MenuItem.getActionView()' on a null object reference

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal Yes, You need to paste them inside the OnCreateOptionsMenu(); But it's just returns the searched query!

Comment: You must first need to create an xml for search menu item then you can get it's reference in activity . If you do not create search menu in xml you get null pointers exception